# WinAPI: set fill color of a readonly textbox

Tags: winapi, colors, textbox, readonly, fill

I have a program winapi (C++) nearly complete. The problem now is I want to set fill color of text box and that textbox is readonly. When I set that textbox readonly, I can't fill it white. And when I don't, it can be filled with white.
This is how I create a textbox:

```
CreateWindow(L"EDIT", text, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|ES_READONLY|ES_RIGHT, left, top, width, height, hWnd, (HMENU)ID, hInst, NULL)
```

And this code is in WinProc:

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        SetTextColor((HDC)wParam,RGB(0,0,255));
        SetBkColor((HDC)wParam,RGB(255,255,255));
        SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` for read-only text boxes; see the docs for [`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: yes, I tried with WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, the textbox is white now but the label background was white too (the background of app is light grey). I don't want this happens.

`case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
   SetTextColor((HDC)wParam,RGB(0,0,255));
   SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255,255,255));
   SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
  return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);`

Answer (score 0):

As per HerrJoebob's solution, but you need to differentiate between static's and edit's: (untested code, but the idea is there)

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
TCHAR senderClass[256] ;
GetClassName((HWND)lParam, senderClass, 256);
if (_tscmp(senderClass, WC_EDIT)
  {
  //Code to change the colour of edit controls
  }
}
break;
```